# how to access elements of a list present as a value in key-value pair in a map ,where map is present in another list in Dart

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

let the given list is:

```
  var questions = [
     {
       'questiontext': 'What\'s your favourite color?',
       'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
     },
     {
       'questiontext': 'What\'s your favourite animal?',
       'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Lion', 'Snake'],
     },];
```

if I want to access each element of 'answers' key-value pair of 0th element of questions array.
how would we do that??

I am trying
`questions[0]['answers'][0]`..but it is giving errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You should pay attention to the error message you get.  If you don't understand the error message, you at least should mention *what* error you get so that others can help you more easily and so that other people can find your question more easily when searching.)

`questions[0]['answers'][0]` doesn't work, failing with: `Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.`  That provides a hint what's wrong: a type is being inferred as `Object` instead of as a more specific type, and then you try to use `operator []` on it.

And indeed, your `Map`s have heterogeneous values: `questiontext` maps to a `String`, but `answers` maps to a `List<String>`.  Your `Map`s therefore are inferred to be of type `Map<String, Object>` since `Object` is the common base class of `String` and `List<String>`.

Ways to fix your code:

- Explicitly use `dynamic` to disable static type-checking:

  ```dart
  var questions = <Map<String, dynamic>>[...];
  ```
- Explicitly cast when doing lookups:

  ```dart
  print((questions[0]['answers'] as List<String>)[0]); // Prints: Black
  ```
- Use a class instead of a `Map`, which is more appropriate since you have different types for different fields:

  ```dart
  class QuestionAndAnswers {
    QuestionAndAnswers(this.questionText, this.answers);

    String questionText;
    List<String> answers;
  }

  var questions = [
    QuestionAndAnswers(
      'What\'s your favourite color?',
      ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
    ),
    ...
  ];

  print(questions[0].answers[0]); // Prints: Black
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Because the map value can either be a `String` or a `List<String>`, the maps types are inferred to be `Map<String, dynamic>`. This means that you have to cast the value :

```
print((questions[0]['answers'] as List<String>)[0]);
```